# singleton shared preferences issue

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, singleton, sharedpreferences

This just an example of my application.

I have created a singleton shared preferences which used a custom Shared preference manager class to edit the shared preferences data values:

```
public class MySharedPrefManager {
    private static MySharedPrefManager instance= null;
    private static SharedPreferences SharedPref;
    private static Editor SPEditor;

    private  MySharedPrefManager () {
    }
    public static MySharedPrefManager getInstance(){
        if(instance==null)
            instance= new MySharedPrefManager ();
        return instance;
    }

    public void setSharedPreferences(Context context){
        SharedPref= context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SPEditor= SPEditor.edit();
    }
    public void setAdmin(boolean pAdmin) {
        SharedPrefManager.editBoolean("isAdmin", pAdmin, SPEditor);
    }
    public boolean isAdmin() {          
        return SharedPref.getBoolean("isAdmin", false);
    }
}
```

Shared preference manager:

```
public class SharedPrefManager {
    public static void editString(String key, String value, Editor pEditor){
        pEditor.putString(key, value);
        pEditor.commit();
    }
    public static void editBoolean(String key, boolean value, Editor pEditor){
        pEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
        pEditor.commit();
    }
```

I have lots of activities which goes like activities: A->B->C->D->E->F->G

Activity A, which is the start-up activity, i get the instance of MySharedPrefManager and set the SharedPreferences also:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
    private MySharedPrefManager myPref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.initialization);

        myPref= MySharedPrefManager.getInstance();
        // I am setting the SharedPreference Context with getApplicationContext(),
        // as it is singleton, and I am using it through out my application
        myPref.setSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        // other stuff...
    }

    private void changeData(){
        myPref.setAdmin(true);
    }

    private void check(){
        if(myPref.isAdmin()){
            // do- something
        }
    }
}
```

ActivityD :

```
public class ActivityD extends Activity{

    private MySharedPrefManager myPref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.initialization);
        // Here i called only the instance not the setSharedPreferences.
        myPref= MySharedPrefManager.getInstance();

        // other stuff...
    }
    private void changeData(){
        myPref.setAdmin(true);
    }
    private void check(){
        if(myPref.isAdmin()){
            // do- something
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the issue I am facing right now is that, some times I get **Null pointer exception in myPref.isAdmin()** when I call it both in Activity A and D. But most of the time it works.

Also do I need to set the **SharedPreferences (call the setSharedPreferences() method) in each of the activities?** I don't feel the need to set is as it is singleton class.

I repeat, I am setting the SharedPreference Context with getApplicationContext(),as it is singleton and I am using it through out my application.

**Edited:** There are 3-4 shared preferences that I am using with the same structure.. With the similar problem. Using this **PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);**, I will be able to use only ONE SharedPreference which is the default SharedPreference.

Comment: try `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the data members or contents of the MySharedPrefManager, check for the null-check.

In MySharedPrefManager class add a getter method like this:

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreference(){
    return SharedPref;
}
```

In the activity where you are accessing shared preference contents, in onCreate or onResume add this before using the contents:

```
myPref= MySharedPrefManager.getInstance();
if(myPref.getSharedPreference()==null){
    myPref.setSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}
```

This way you will be able to avoid NPE.

Answer (score 2):

The null pointer exception is probably caused by your singleton not being initialized. I suppose this happens when you rotate your device?

I expect the following to be happening: In activity A you do `getInstance()` and `setSharedPreferences()`. In activity B you only do `getInstance()` and expect to get the same instance that was created in A. But if you rotate the device while in B, then B is recreated which does the `getInstance()`, but this time it has to create its instance itself. And this time it will not do the initialization with `setSharedPreferences()`.

My advise is to make your prefs class simpler. Make sure you initialize on construction. I.e. do not separate out `getInstance()` and `setSharedPreferences()`. Do something like this:

```
public class MySharedPrefManager {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    private MySharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static MySharedPrefManager from(Context context) {
        return new MySharedPrefManager(context);
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean pAdmin) {
        sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("isAdmin", pAdmin).apply();
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return sharedPref.getBoolean("isAdmin", false);
    }
}
```

And use it like this when you need to do multiple settings:

```
MySharedPrefManager prefs = MySharedPrefManager.from(this);
prefs.setAdmin(true);
prefs.setSomethingElse();
boolean isFoo = prefs.isFoo();
```

Or use the shorter version if you only need one setting:

```
MySharedPrefManager.from(this).setAdmin(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to, there already is a singleton. You can do:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```